# For loop inside for loop messing up variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Hello I am trying to rearrange / sort my projectsDATA variable in alphabetical order. But when I run the sort() function in the console my code just messes up my variables. For instance if my projectsDATA variable would be:

```
var projectsDATA = [B, C, D, A];
```

If I would run my code with this variable the output would be [A, C, C, A], but the output doesn't seem "systematic".

I hope you understand my problem.

I have checked everything in my code to figure out how to solve this problem, and I have located that the problem occurs in the 3. for loop looking like this:

```
for(var index2 = 0; index2 < projectsDATAcopy.length; index2 = index2 + 1){
        if (arrayChecked[index] == projectsDATAcopy[index2].title) {
            console.log(arrayChecked[index], projectsDATA[index], projectsDATAcopy[index2]);
            projectsDATA[index] = projectsDATAcopy[index2];
        }
    }
```

I know my code isn't perfect but any help would be appreciated :)

```
var projectsDATA = [
    {
        "href":"/cancerSimulation",
        "theclass":"p5js websites",
        "btnValue": "Cancer Simulator",
        "title": "Aancer Simulation",
        "description": "Cancer Simulation as addition to exam project Cancer Simulation as addition to exam project Cancer Simulation as addition to exam project Cancer Simulation as addition to exam project",
        "date":[2017, "2017",5, "may"]
    },
    {
        "href":"/encryptionProject",
        "theclass":"websites",
        "btnValue": "Facebook Encryption Tool",
        "title": "Bacebook Encryption Tool",
        "description": "Facebook Encryption Tool",
        "date":[2016, "2016",12, "December"]
    },
    {
        "href":"/encryptionProject",
        "theclass":"websites",
        "btnValue": "Facebook Encryption Tool",
        "title": "Dacebook Encryption Tool",
        "description": "Facebook Encryption Tool",
        "date":[2016, "2016",12, "December"]
    }, 
    {
        "href":"/encryptionProject",
        "theclass":"websites",
        "btnValue": "Facebook Encryption Tool",
        "title": "Cacebook Encryption Tool",
        "description": "Facebook Encryption Tool",
        "date":[2016, "2016",12, "December"]
    }
];

var projectsDATAcopy;
console.log(projectsDATA);
var arrayCheck = [];
var arrayChecked;

function sort() {
    projectsDATAcopy = projectsDATA;
    console.log(projectsDATAcopy, projectsDATA);
    var sortValue = document.getElementById("sorting").value;

    if (sortValue == "Alphabetical") {
        for(var index3 = 0; index3 < projectsDATAcopy.length; index3++){
            arrayCheck[index3] = projectsDATAcopy[index3].title;
            console.log(arrayCheck);
        }
        arrayChecked = arrayCheck.sort();
        console.log(arrayChecked);
        console.log(projectsDATAcopy, projectsDATA);

        for(var index = 0; index < arrayChecked.length; index = index +1){
            console.log(arrayChecked[index]);
            for(var index2 = 0; index2 < projectsDATAcopy.length; index2 = index2 + 1){
                if (arrayChecked[index] == projectsDATAcopy[index2].title) {
                    console.log(arrayChecked[index], projectsDATA[index], projectsDATAcopy[index2]);
                    projectsDATA[index] = projectsDATAcopy[index2];
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(projectsDATA);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shoud swap the two cells of the array not override one with the other.

Comment: ... And that's not how you copy arrays.

Comment: If you're trying to sort an array, why are you not using the built-in `.sort` method?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir How do I copy arrays correctly?

Comment: Use means like `Array.prototype.slice`, `Array.from` or `Array.prototype.map`. But, then you'll be only copying the references to the object stored in the array (the object will still be the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to use [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
projects.sort((projectX, projectY) => projectX.title.localeCompare(projectY.title));
```

Unfortunately, this mutates the original array which is often undesirable. We can mitigate this by using [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to create a copy of the original array before sorting it. Since we are creating a brand new array we store the result of the sort operation in a new variable.

```
const sortedProjects = projects
  .slice()
  .sort((projectX, projectY) => projectX.title.localeCompare(projectY.title));
```

Here it is in action over your sample data

```js
const projects = [{
    "href": "/cancerSimulation",
    "theclass": "p5js websites",
    "btnValue": "Cancer Simulator",
    "title": "Aancer Simulation",
    "description": "Cancer Simulation as addition to exam project Cancer Simulation as addition to exam project Cancer Simulation as addition to exam project Cancer Simulation as addition to exam project",
    "date": [2017, "2017", 5, "may"]
  },
  {
    "href": "/encryptionProject",
    "theclass": "websites",
    "btnValue": "Facebook Encryption Tool",
    "title": "Bacebook Encryption Tool",
    "description": "Facebook Encryption Tool",
    "date": [2016, "2016", 12, "December"]
  },
  {
    "href": "/encryptionProject",
    "theclass": "websites",
    "btnValue": "Facebook Encryption Tool",
    "title": "Dacebook Encryption Tool",
    "description": "Facebook Encryption Tool",
    "date": [2016, "2016", 12, "December"]
  },
  {
    "href": "/encryptionProject",
    "theclass": "websites",
    "btnValue": "Facebook Encryption Tool",
    "title": "Cacebook Encryption Tool",
    "description": "Facebook Encryption Tool",
    "date": [2016, "2016", 12, "December"]
  }
];

const sortedProjects = projects
  .slice()
  .sort((projectX, projectY) => projectX.title.localeCompare(projectY.title));
  
console.log(sortedProjects)
```

**Remarks:**

In the example code, I use `const` to declare my locals. When a name will not be rebound, `const` is superior to `let` since it conveys that information immediately to the reader. It frees the reader from having to think about the current state of the *reference* `sortedProjects` as they continue to read since it cannot change. Note the array that is referred to is still mutable.

`slice` create a shallow copy of an array or a subset of an array. When no arguments are specified, it simply creates a shallow copy of the entire array. By shallow copy, I mean that only the references to the objects at each index in the array are copied. The two arrays still share the same underlying objects, just arranged in different orders. The inline hyperlink to the MDN documentation for `slice` explains this behavior in detail.

Comment: Thank You Aluan. Your solution seems to be working. It's amazing :)

Comment: Can I just ask you why do you call the project variable a const? What does this do? Also if you have time then I would love to see an explanation of why this works      .slice()
  .sort((projectX, projectY) => projectX.title.localeCompare(projectY.title));

Comment: Glad to help. The built in Array methods are very useful. Check out [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for some extremely useful general purpose functionality.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to sort your array *by key*. This can easily be done like this example below shows. In this case our key is `name` of the dictionary:

```
var projectsDATA = [
  {'name': 'X', 'value': 24},
  {'name': 'Y', 'value': 25},
  {'name': 'Z', 'value': 26},
  {'name': 'A', 'value': 1},
  {'name': 'B', 'value': 2},
  {'name': 'C', 'value': 3}
];

console.log(projectsDATA);

// Note ".slice()" which makes a shallow copy of your array

sorted = projectsDATA.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a['name'] < b['name']) return -1;
  if (a['name'] > b['name']) return 1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(sorted);
```

You can generalize this with a function `sortByKey`:

```
sortByKey = function(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1;
      if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
};
```

and sort by `value` or `name`:

```
console.log(sortByKey(projectsDATA, 'value'));
console.log(sortByKey(projectsDATA, 'name'));
```